What webdav types of authorization are supported in the latest version of office 365 on MacOS?
Some time ago I developed WebDAV functionality in my PHP application. In it, I used basic authentication to identify the user in the system. We respond to requests without authentication with the appropriate response in the headers:
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=example, charset="UTF-8".
I recently ran into an issue where editing via WebDAV stopped working. After analyzing the error, I discovered that the problem only occurs in the most recent versions of Office macOS. More precisely, the upgrade from 16.81 to 16.84 causes incorrect behavior. The problem is that instead of sending headers from Word:
Authorization: Basic XXX
MS Word now sends:
Authorization: Bearer (empty here)
Hence the question, has Microsoft disabled support for basic authentication? The request to enter your login/password still appears, the credentials are simply not sent.
Is there any way to solve this problem other than implementing support for a different authentication scheme?
What authentication schemes are supported in modern versions?
Here are the available authorization types that send in MS Word headers to my server:
"accept-auth": [ "badger,Wlid1.1,Bearer,Basic,NTLM,Digest,Kerberos,Negotiate,Nego2" ]

Full client headers:
{
  "host": [
    "default.stage-wiki.vpool.qsoft.ru"
  ],
  "x-real-ip": [
    "10.42.0.183"
  ],
  "x-forwarded-for": [
    "10.42.0.183, 10.42.0.183"
  ],
  "connection": [
    "close"
  ],
  "user-agent": [
    "Microsoft Office Excel/16.84.414 (Mac OS/13.2.1; Desktop; ru-RU; NonAppStore; Apple/MacBookPro16,3)"
  ],
  "accept": [
    "*/*"
  ],
  "accept-auth": [
    "badger,Wlid1.1,Bearer,Basic,NTLM,Digest,Kerberos,Negotiate,Nego2"
  ],
  "accept-encoding": [
    "gzip, deflate, br"
  ],
  "accept-language": [
    "ru"
  ],
  "authorization": [
    "Bearer"
  ],
  "x-featureversion": [
    "1"
  ],
  "x-forwarded-host": [
    "default.stage-wiki.vpool.qsoft.ru"
  ],
  "x-forwarded-port": [
    "80"
  ],
  "x-forwarded-proto": [
    "http"
  ],
  "x-forwarded-server": [
    "traefik-f54bc5cb8-z2dwh"
  ],
  "x-ms-cookieuri-requested": [
    "t"
  ],
  "x-msgetweburl": [
    "t"
  ],
  "x-office-major-version": [
    "16"
  ],
  "x-request-id": [
    "ac059dea-711f-43be-9e48-99647427eb79"
  ],
  "x-account-slug": [
    "default"
  ]
}


Here are the available authorization types that send in MS Word headers to my server....it says "Basic" in those headers. So doesn't that answer your question already? Maybe it's just not the default in the installation you're testing with? Have you asked Microsoft about this?

@ADyson yes, I contacted Microsoft technical support, from there they sent me to their forum, and from the forum they sent me to stackoverflow. The authorization behavior in the new version is very similar to a bug on Microsoft's part, but I also assume that they have disabled support for basic authorization. Therefore, I am writing here to ask other users if they have encountered a similar problem.

Really their technical support should answer your question directly, rather than offloading their work onto volunteers.

They told me that their technical support is aimed at resolving issues of license, installation and other basic things

I am intimately familiar with this topic and I can tell you that MS-OFBA and MS-OAUTH2EX are supported.
